# DPDK pktgen EAL: rte_service_init failed EAL Initialization error

Tags: linux, docker, memory, containers, dpdk

I am trying to run this command in DPDK:

```
pktgen -a $SN_PCIE_DEV.0 -a $SN_PCIE_DEV.1 -l 4-8 -n 4 -d librte_net_qdma.so --file-prefix $SN_PCIE_DEV- -- -v -m [5:6].0 -m [7:8].1
```

but I am getting:

```
*** Copyright(c) <2010-2023>, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
*** Pktgen  created by: Keith Wiles -- >>> Powered by DPDK <<<

EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 96
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 2
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/0000:ac:00-/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: error allocating rte services array
EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed
EAL: rte_service_init() failed
```

Background:

DPDK is running inside a docker container. The host is a docker container itself, so DPDK is running in docker in docker. The host has hugepages and hugetlbs showing up in `cat /proc/meminfo`

The inside docker container (the one running DPDK) has hugepages and hugetlbs showing up in `cat /proc/meminfo`, but pktgen won't find the hugepages until I run:

```
sudo mount -t hugetlbfs -o pagesize=1G none /dev/hugepages
```

pktgen is being executed with root privileges and both containers and privileged.

I tried everything I can find on stackoverflow.